# Multiple threads calling a method while blocking if another method is called from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Suppose there are two methods `methodA()` and `methodB()` that are called from distinct threads. What I want is when `methodA()` is called then the thread that called `methodB()` be blocked until `methodA()` is finished, and the other way round. This can be easily achieved with a semaphore:

```
private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);

public void methodA() {//ignored try catch finally
    semaphore.acquire();
    //do stuff
    semaphore.release();
}

public void methodB() {
    semaphore.acquire();
    //do stuff
    semaphore.release();
}
```

But the thing is that I want multiple threads executing concurrently `methodA()` or `methodB()`. **Multiple threads should be able to execute at the same time `methodA()` so long no one executes `methodB()`**; the above solution does not work in this case because if a thread executes `methodA()` no other thread can execute `methodA()` even if there is no thread executing `methodB()`.

Any other solution I can think of either needs synchronization in methods or does something else that does not allow multiple threads executing a single method if no threads execute the other one.

Comment: Are you trying to specifically avoid synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation very much like a trafficlight at a crossroads. Either road A gets to pass or road B, but never both simultaneously.

So let's say we have a `TrafficLight` class that acts a little like a `Semaphore` that monitors two roads "A" and "B". A thread wanting to pass "A" can ask permission for "A" and shall be granted that permission, or block if a "B" permission has not been released, and vice versa.

In the past I have made such a `TrafficLight` class as an exercise (which can actually monitor more than 2 states) :

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class TrafficLight<T> {

    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    private Condition switched = lock.newCondition();
    private int registered;
    private int maxBeforeYield = 20;
    private T state;

    public void acquire(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while ((state != null && !state.equals(t)) || maxBeforeYield == 0) {
                switched.await();
            }
            if (state == null) {
                state = t;
            }
            registered++;
            maxBeforeYield--;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            registered--;
            if (registered == 0) {
                state = null;
                maxBeforeYield = 20;
                switched.signalAll();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `maxBeforeYield` : one problem the TrafficLight may encounter is that so a flood of requests for "A" is so great, that requests for "B" never get a chance. Therefore the TrafficLight counts requests, and after a number of requests (`maxBeforeYield`) it starts blocking "A" requests as well, then nicely waits until all permissions have been returned, and then gives another state a chance, the `ReentrantLock` needs to be fair, to make sure the 'direction' switches unless only requests for the same direction are blocked.

Given this `TrafficLight` class you could change your code into :

```
private TrafficLight<String> trafficLight = new TrafficLight<>();

public void methodA() {//ignored try catch finally
    trafficLight.acquire("A");
    //do stuff
    trafficLight.release();
}

public void methodB() {
    trafficLight.acquire("B");
    //do stuff
    trafficLight.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a reader/writer lock (e.g., java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock).  It allows any number of 'readers' to use the resource at the same --OR-- it allows exactly one 'writer' to use it, but not both.

A good implementation, like the Java version, will be slightly complicated by the need to provide 'fairness.'  E.g., it must not 'starve' a writer that wants the resource even when there are so many readers that there is *never* a moment when the resource is idle.